# Is there a fix for the "Could not find *gem* in any of the sources" error that doesn't involve deleting Gemfile.lock?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying to get my development environment setup on a new computer.

```
git clone -o heroku git@heroku.com:theirapp.git
cd theirapp
bundle
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/......
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
Could not find jquery-rails-2.0.0 in any of the sources
```

After googling this error, the response seems to be to delete `Gemfile.lock`, then running `bundle` again. This works, but then I have different versions of gems where I haven't specified a version in `Gemfile`. Is there a way to fix this error without deleting `Gemfile.lock`? I'm using Rails 3.2 and Ruby 1.9.3.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11876788/heroku-push-rejected-cant-find-jquery-rails-2-0-0-in-sources. The accepted answer is similar to this one and also dangerous so check the other answers.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

According to rubygems.org, jquery-rails 2.0.0 has been [yanked](http://rubygems.org/gems/jquery-rails/versions). That explains the error you had with jquery-rails.

Running `$ bundle update jquery-rails` will rebuild your gem snapshot. That way you don't have to delete Gemfile.lock

Comment: But that will update all of my gems that don't have versions specified right? That's what I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: You can use $ bundle update <gem_name> to only update a specific gem.

Comment: This answer should be updated to reflect the fact that running straight `bundle update` is a *bad* idea in general. It's essentially the exact same thing as deleting Gemfile.lock. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11876788/heroku-push-rejected-cant-find-jquery-rails-2-0-0-in-sources/12048770#12048770

Answer (score 46):

simply run

```
bundle --full-index
```

that should do the trick

Comment: Yup, that's what I was looking for, as well. I had recently published a gem, and was encountering the "not found" error. Thanks!

Comment: what does this do? `bundle --help` does not have an option listed for `--full-index`

Comment: @johnsimer as [bundler.io](https://bundler.io/v1.2/bundle_install.html) states the option `--full-index` uses the modern index instead of the API endpoint.
For some reason this is more exhaustive than  without that option

Answer (score 8):

An old version of bundler was giving me this same issue.  After a bunch of puzzling, I realized that this was the issue.

Running `gem install bundler` fixed it completely.

Answer (score 4):

I've found it safest ALWAYS to specify gem versions, and only change them when necessary. Saved me a LOT of trouble.

Answer (score 4):

`bundle update jquery-rails` will update just the `jquery-rails` gem, which is likely what you're looking for. Running `bundle update` is the equivalent of deleting `Gemfile.lock` and is not recommended in most cases. See here: [Heroku push rejected: can't find jquery-rails-2.0.0 in sources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11876788/heroku-push-rejected-cant-find-jquery-rails-2-0-0-in-sources/12048770#12048770)

Answer (score 3):

In my case, the only thing that helped was a

```
bundle install --force
```

Looked like bundler thought the dependencies have been installed.
But turns out it wasn't correctly.

Comment: Update: The `--force` option was renamed to `--redownload`

Answer (score 1):

In my case, this error was caused by a frozen lockfile.  Editing `my-repository-root/.bundle/config` to set `BUNDLE_FROZEN: "false"` fixed the problem.

`bundle install` did not change the lockfile afterwards, so I don't understand why `BUNDLE_FROZEN` broke anything to begin with...

Answer (score 1):

For me
`bundle update`
followed by `gem pristine racc` worked. It was something related to native repository.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue but with a different gem.
Running `gem install yourgem -v 1.x.x` solved my problem.