# Could not find rake-12.3.1 in any of the sources

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake, capistrano, gemfile

I was deploying rails version on the server by using `capistrano` gem
but it informing me

```
Could not find rake-12.3.1 in any of the sources
```

after that I used `bundle update` to update the bundle and my gemfile but the issue still with me.
then I removed all the `Gemfile.lock` content and used `bundle install` and still get the same issue!!!

BTW I checked my `vendor/cache` and found it contain the file `rake-12.3.1.gem` and my gem file also contain `gem 'rake', '12.3.1'`
so why I got this issue?!

Can anyone help me to fix it?!

Comment: Is your source "https://rubygems.org"?

Comment: How you run deploy? Show exact command please.

Comment: bundle exec cap production deploy

Comment: Check that Ruby is properly installed on the server and that is using the latest versions of Bundler and Rubygems. `gem update --system && gem install bundler`

Comment: Hi @MattBrictson, I checked the server bundle and found it 1.16.1 and it's the same version also on my laptop locally !!
So why I got this issue?!

Comment: I also removed the .bundle file , removed the Gemfile.lock file removed my cache folder  from vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/cache/ and run  gem update --system , bundle install --binstubs , gem install bundler and bundle install

but still got the same error!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: @wmakley yes it's   (source 'https://rubygems.org')

Comment: Sorry, I've seen this kind of error before, but it is one of those where you've probably made a subtle mistake somewhere in the Gemfile, somewhere in the project configuration (maybe it is looking for the gem locally), OR there is something wrong with the server. Have you tried switching to a different version of rake?

Comment: @wmakley,
no I did't  switching rake, in my case also I didn't adding or removing any thing from the project, just added the gems  (gem 'chartkick' , gem 'chartable')  in my  Gemfile, If I adding them  the project giving me this issue, when I removing them the project working well,  actually you can say that there's ghost riding the project with them :(

Comment: Where is the error coming from? Can you post the log output of Capistrano leading up to the error?

Comment: @MattBrictson, in deploying its giving me (Could not find rake-12.3.1 in any of the sources)

Comment: Do you really have `ruby` and `ruby-dev` in your system [1](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/295008), @Astm? Also, `openssl` [2](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/292816)?

Comment: @BerkhanBerkdemir, I have (ruby 2.2.0p0 (2014-12-25 revision 49005) [x86_64-darwin13]), also ( OpenSSH_6.2p2, OSSLShim 0.9.8r 8 Dec 2011 )

Comment: @Astm could you check that too [1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37301669/8929392)

Comment: I don't remember clearly but I think, I solved that problem with `bundle update`. Also, could you share with us the `Gemfile`?

Comment: have you tried `before_install: bundle install --local` in travis.yml config?

Comment: not using travis , we using Capistrano gem

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for you all, I fixed this issue since long time, I found it related with my current ruby version, the application was created by ruby 2.4 & I was using ruby 2.3

Answer (score -1):

Because you have cached the gem in the `vendor/cache` folder, I believe you should add the following line into `.travis.yml`, using the local version of gem store:

```
before_install: bundle install --local
```