# Could not find mime-types-1.25.1 in any of the sources (Bundler::GemNotFound)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bundler

When deploying app to the production server, I navigate to the URL and get the error `Could not find mime-types-1.25.1 in any of the sources (Bundler::GemNotFound).`

The gem is most certainly there but it's still not found.

```
$ bundle show mime-types
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/mime-types-1.25.1
```

As explained here [Heroku push rejected: can't find jquery-rails-2.0.0 in sources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11876788/heroku-push-rejected-cant-find-jquery-rails-2-0-0-in-sources/12048770#12048770) Deleting the Gemfile.lock is the wrong thing to do, and this version of mime-types is the latest.

Comment: Could you add information about your production server? Are you using Apache and Passenger, or Unicorn, or Puma, etc? Is it possible that the server is running with a different version of Ruby?

Comment: @TimMoore It was that my version of ruby had somehow got upgraded on the server. Thanks!

Comment: Matt, can you write up what happened as an answer to your question and then accept that answer.  It can be helpful for people who end up in a similar scenario,

Comment: Please tell me how you fixed it? I'm having the same problem